# servlet getting null values when i retrieve values from jsp form

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, servlets

this is my jsp page.where im displaying a form and sending the values to another servlet page to insert the data into mysql database.im using post method to send all values.servlet name is updateVehicle2

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Modify Vehicle</title>
</head>

<center><h1> Modify Vehicle</h1></center>
<center>
<form action="updateVehicle2" method="Post">
    <label >Enter Vehicle name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="vname" required><br><br>
     <label >Enter Vehicle model:</label>
    <input type="text" name="vmodel" required ><br><br>
    <label >Enter Vehicle ID:</label>
    <input type="text" name="vid"  required ><br><br>
     <label >Select Vehicle type:</label>
    <select name="vtype" required>
        <option disabled selected>select type</option>
        <option value="Ac">Ac</option>
        <option value="NonAc">Non Ac</option>
    </select><br><br>

     <label >Rate per hour:</label>
    <input type="text" name="vrph" required ><br><br>
    <label >Rate per km:</label>
    <input type="text" name="vrpk" required ><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Vehicles">

</form></center>
```

this is my servlet page.here im trying to retrieve values by using request.getParameter() ,but im getting null values here.every values is null.i have used name attribute for retrieving values .but,still it returning null values.please help me struggling with this problem morethan 5 hours.thanks in advance

```
String vn=request.getParameter("vname");
   String vmodel=request.getParameter("vmodel");
   String vid=request.getParameter("vid");
   String vtype=request.getParameter("vtype");
   String vrph=request.getParameter("vrph");
   String vrpk=request.getParameter("vrpk");
   response.setContentType("text/html");
   final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
   final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/startrek";
   final String user="root";
   final String pass="kingmaker";
   Connection conn=null;
   PreparedStatement stmt;
   stmt = null;
   int numRows=0;
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   out.println(vn);
   out.println(vmodel);
    try 
    {
       Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,user,pass);
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("update vehicles set vname=?,vmodel=?,vtype=?,vrph=?,vrpk=? where vid=?;");
        stmt.setString(1,vn);
        stmt.setString(2,vmodel);
        stmt.setString(3,vtype);
        stmt.setString(4,vrph);
        stmt.setString(5,vrpk);
        stmt.setString(6,vid);

        numRows=stmt.executeUpdate();
        if(numRows>0)
        {
            out.println("updated successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            out.println("not succesfully");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        out.println(e);
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: Post your web.xml and full code of servlet.

Comment: <servlet>
        <servlet-name>updateVehicle2</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>updateVehicle2</servlet-class>
    </servlet><servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>updateVehicle2</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/updateVehicle2</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: i have already posted my servlet code above please check it oonce

Comment: actually problem solved.i had done mistake in url mapping in web.xml.thanks for your concern

Answer (score -1):

To overcome from this problem write '@MultipartConfig' before your Servlet class.
like-->

@MultipartConfig
`public class EditUserServlet extends HttpServlet {}`